# How do I connect my database to local SQL Server Express using nose js

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server

I am using Express framework and trying to connect to my SQL Server Express database locally. I am getting error - connection failure. I need help with that, if you'd please.

Steps completed so far..

1. npm install mssql
2. var sql = require("mssql");

   ```
   // config for your database
   var config = {
       user: 'ImacamUser',
       password: '*****',
       server: 'localhost', 
       database: 'InvoicingData' 
   };
   ```
3. ```
    sql.connect(config, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from Customers', function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);        
        });
    });
   ```

The error I get from this code is:

> ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
>
> at C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
> at Connection.onConnect (C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
> at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
> at Connection.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at Connection.emit (C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:12)
> at C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1176:14
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> originalError: ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)
> at Connection.socketError (C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1395:28)
> at C:\Projects\RCN\Invoicing\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1176:14
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
> code: 'ESOCKET',
> isTransient: undefined
> }

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Normally, unless you changed the defaults, the SQL Server **Express** edition is installed as the named instance `SQLEXPRESS` - so your server name in the SQL connection config should be `server: 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'`

Comment: Nose js? That's a new one

Comment: It's an odd framework to pick.

Comment: @marc_s - Thanks for the help. After adding the named instance, I received a more specific error description which was related to trusted connection setting. So, added trustServerCertificate: false as an option to the config. That fixed the issue.